# What are the main obstacles to seeing the Northern Lights in Reykjavik in December?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, iceland, auroras

We are looking at visiting Reykjavik in December to see the Northern Lights. I have done some initial research on the [weather in December](https://weatherspark.com/averages/27562/12/Reykjavik-Capital-Region-Iceland) and I know there will only be about 4 hours of daylight, so it should be a good time to see the Northern lights.

What are the main obstacles to going to see the Northern Lights in December?

Comment: You might have to narrow this down. Obstacles like what? Terrain? Weather? Asteroids? Armageddon?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TSE. I have changed the wording of your question a little bit. This might make it less opinion based. If you feel the edit goes against your intentions, you can roll it back. I've decided not to vote regarding the closure of this question, as I'm not sure. Also, do consider narrowing this down in the fashion suggested by @JoErNanO . This may save your question from closure.

Comment: Clouds ? low or no solar activities ?